# no ajax response using local wamp server

Tags: ajax

I'm blocked on a very problematic error.

I have to manage a drupal 7 site, production running on LAMP server and there is a little bug that I have to fix. I don't develop this site, just I am the new webmaster.

To develop new content or test some fixature, I have a local copy of the site ( Win8, WAMP2 ).

The problem is that I have to create some contents on my local version of the site to reproduce the problem but when I click to add field to my content. It send an ajax request and I receive an empty response and my page don't display the html form that it should display. I precise that I have a response not an error but content of it is empty.

Ajax request works on production server.

I try to trace the request using firebug but I don't found name of the callback function. Request is send to `http://127.0.0.1/system/ajax`. The page is a form created by ajax.

What can be the source of this problem ? Maybe a difference of configuration from apache, in this case which parameter could be the responsible ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is a kind of WSOD - the worse because it's AJAX related. You can search here and on the internet about how to deal with WSODs. First thing is to check your apache's error.log

Comment: I just have startup and shutdown notifications in apache error.log, no error related, I will take a look on google with WSOD term.

Comment: "White Screen Of Death" - something happens but it seems no error message and no data was generated. It's pretty common and there are semi-standard ways to deal with them, or at least identify real cause. And it they fail, tell us at least how you tried.

Comment: Any idea about how I can repear the callback function for this ajax request ? like that I could inspect what happenning on server side.

Comment: [php module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/php) allows you to call anything from a node, for example.

Comment: Hello, I'm coming back with new ways to explore. I never succeed to fix the problem but now I think it's related to memcache usage : I have to download again all the site and the problem not append anymore for a few time and now the problem come back. On production, the site is on a linux server but I manage it on a windows desktop with WAMP, so I always have some warnings ( 700/page ) about memcache. so as it's work perfectly on production and not on my desktop I think it is not just a coincidence

Comment: Why would you believe so?